# Ideal characterization technique to study behavior of heated metal nitrates

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, precipitation

I have 3-4 metal nitrates as precursors for my coprecipitation reaction. I need to study the behavior of each individual nitrate and also of various combinations at 60 degrees Celsius, which is my experiment temperature. Which characterization technique would be most suitable to study the change in each case if any?

I have the following nitrates-

1)Barium nitrate

2)Aluminum nitrate nonahydrate

3)Iron nitrate nonahydrate

4)Cobalt nitrate hexahydrate

5)Cerium nitrate hexahydrate

The solvent is water for each solution. I need to know whether any nitrate will decompose or undergo any structural changes. I am trying to reach all these nitrates with ammonium carbonate to precipitate carbonates of all.

Comment: I find the question unclear. What nitrates, exactly? What change at 60 °C do you expect? What type of characterization do you need? What are you trying to precipitate? What solvent are you working with?

Comment: @andselisk I have edited the question.Please take a look

Comment: Fe, Co and Ce are variable valence metals: it's not clear from "*Iron nitrate*" whether it is Iron(II) nitrate or iron(III) nitrate. All of them will undergo structural changes upon dilution, and some may hydrolyse. Whether a metal carbonate will or will not precipitate can be evident from the corresponding $K_\mathrm{sp}$ values or solubility charts all of which are freely available.

Comment: @andselisk Its Iron(III).My question is what changes will the metal salt solution will undergo after heating at 60 deg cel, and whether there is any characterization technique to characterize the change